# Get current preset Onvif

Tags: c#, onvif, preset

Is there a way to get current preset using `Onvif` programming (using `c#`)?
I can set, remove, update and go to preset but I can't find a way to know if my `PTZClient` is positioned in a specific preset.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method for that. But the device could emit the event `tns1:PTZController/PTZPresets/Reached` , see §5.11.1 of the [PTZ Service specs](https://www.onvif.org/onvif/specs/srv/ptz/ONVIF-PTZ-Service-Spec.pdf).